# Random variables probability-infinite coin toss

Tags: probability

In the infinite coin toss let $X$ -be the number of $H$s in $3$ tosses. Calculate $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$. Let $Y$ be random variable corresponding to the number of $H$s in first two tosses, $\mathcal{G}=σ(Y)$. 
I know that there are sets for $Y(0)$ $Y(1)$ and $Y(2)$.For $X$ we have $X(\omega)=3$ for $HHH$, $X(\omega)=2$ for $HHT$ $HTH$ $THH$, $X(\omega)=1$ for $TTH$ $HTT$ $THT$ and $X(\omega)=0$ fot $TTT$,but I still don't realise how to calculate $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$??

Comment: I do not understand the definition of $G$. Can you explain?

Comment: for sigma algebra G=σ(Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that there are sets for $Y(0)$, $Y(1)$, and $Y(2)$.

For $\Omega = \{{\sf TTT, TTH, HTT, THT, HTH, THH, HHT, HHH}\}$ and $Y:\Omega\to \{0,1,2\}$, where $Y$ is the count of heads in the first two tosses, we have:

$$\begin{align}Y^{-1}\{0\}=&~\{{\sf TTT, TTH}\} \\ Y^{-1}\{1\} = &~\{{\sf HTT, THT, HTH, THH}\}\\ Y^{-1}\{2\}=&~\{{\sf HHT, HHH}\}\end{align}$$

As $\mathcal G$ is the sigma algebra generated by random variable $Y$ :
$$\mathcal G=\sigma( Y ) = \{\varnothing, Y^{-1}\{0\}, Y^{-1}\{1\}, Y^{-1}\{2\}, Y^{-1}\{0,1\}, Y^{-1}\{0,2\}, Y^{-1}\{1,2\}, \Omega\}$$

You are basically being asked to find :

$$\mathsf E(X\mid \mathcal G)(\gamma)=\begin{cases} 0 & : \gamma= \varnothing\\ 1/2 & : \gamma= Y^{-1}\{0\}\\ \ldots  & : \gamma = Y^{-1}\{1\}\\ \ldots & : \gamma = Y^{-1}\{2\}\\ 7/6 & : \gamma= Y^{-1}\{0,1\}\\ \ldots & : \gamma= Y^{-1}\{0,2\} \\ \ldots & : \gamma= Y^{-1}\{1,2\}\\ 3/2 & : \gamma= \Omega\\ \mathsf{undef} & : \gamma\notin\mathcal G\end{cases}$$

Can you complete?

Comment: Yes, I have received - 
E[X|G](y) = 3/2 : Y{1}, 
E[X|G](y) = 5/2 : Y{2}, 
E[X|G](y) = 3/2 : Y{0,2}, 
E[X|G](y) = 11/6 : Y{1,2}. It looks very simple - thank you a lot!

Comment: Can you please clarify, that in case when we have Y - random variable corresponding to the number of Hs in first FOUR tosses - we have nothing for Y{4}, because for Ω we have maximum set - HHH?

Comment: @Maria You would be using a different space to model that scenario.

Comment: I am sorry, does first task include $Y^-1$ {0,1,2} ?

Comment: @Maria $Y^{-1}\{0,1,2\} = \Omega$

Comment: yes, i have just realised that it is stupid question, but it was too late for editing) Thank you